# Is there an easy way to implement a Normal-inverse-wishart function in Python/PyMc3?

Tags: python, statistics, pymc3

I am curently working with non-parametrical statistics in python using PyMc3. And would like to implement a normal-inverse-wishart function as a prior to my model. But after short research I had to find out that there is no predefined function for that. So before trying to rebuild it all from zero, I wanted to ask you if someone has experience in doing that and if there is an easy way to do it.

Thanks in advance and best regards!
Leon